# Ruby Mechanize: Programmatically Clicking a Link Without Knowing the Name of the Link

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am writing a ruby script to search the web. Here is the code:

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get('http://www.example.com/)
example_page = page.link_with(:text => 'example').click
puts example_page.body
```

The code above works alright. The text 'example' ((:text => 'example') has to be a link on the page for the code to work correctly. The problem, however, is that when I do a web search (bing, yahoo, google, etc), hundreds of links show up. How can I programmatically click a link without knowing the exact name of the link? I want to be able to click a link if the name of the link partly (or fully) matches a text that I specify or click a link if it has a certain  url. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already know the URL, why not just go to that URL? Anyway, seems what you want is to collect all links, filter them for some criteria and click those that satisfy?

Comment: Don't scrape their front-end pages, instead use their APIs.

Comment: Try passing a regex instead of a string, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize has regular expressions:

```
page.link_with(text: /foo/).click
page.link_with(href: /foo/).click
```

Here are the Mechanize criteria that generally work for links and forms:

```
name: name_matcher
id: id_matcher
class: class_matcher
search: search_expression
xpath: xpath_expression
css: css_expression
action: action_matcher
...
```

If you're curious, here's the [Mechanize ElementMatcher code](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/element_matcher.rb)